Issue Accessing JWT Cookies from Backend to Frontend in MERN Stack
#MERN-STACK
I'm encountering difficulties accessing JWT cookies sent from the backend to the frontend in my MERN stack application. While testing in Postman, everything works smoothly, but on the frontend, I'm unable to access or manipulate the cookie to keep the user logged in as long as the JWT token is valid. I'm aiming to implement refresh tokens and ensure the application is production-ready when necessary.
Here's a breakdown of my setup:
Backend Setup (app.js):
// Modules
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoute');
const cartRouter = require('./routes/cartRoute');
const orderRouter = require('./routes/orderRoute');
const errorController = require('./controllers/errorController');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  }),
);
app.options('*', cors({ credentials: true }));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use('/cart', cartRouter);
app.use('/order', orderRouter);
app.use(errorController);


module.exports = app;

Backend Authentication Middleware (authMiddleware.js):
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const AppError = require('./appError');

exports.generateToken = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });

  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  });

};

exports.protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let token = req.cookies.jwt;

    if (!token) {
      return next(
        new AppError('Not authorized: Invalid token - not logged in', 401),
      );
    }
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.userId);

    if (!currentUser) {
      return next(
        new AppError(
          'Not authorized: User belonging to this token no longer exists',
          401,
        ),
      );
    }
    req.user = currentUser;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new AppError('Not authorized: Invalid token', 401));
  }
});

Frontend API Setup (authApi.js):
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';

const authApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10 * 1000,
  // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  withCredentials: true,
});


Frontend Login Logic (login.js):
import { authApi } from './authApi';

async function login({ email, password }) {
  try {
    const res = await authApi.post('users/login', {
      email,
      password,
    });


    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error(error.response.data.message);
  }
}

export { login };

Frontend Login Hook (useLogin.js):
import { useAuth } from '../../context/AuthProvider';
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { login } from '../../services/login';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

function useLogin() {
  const { setUser } = useAuth();

  const { isPending, mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: login,
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      toast.success('Successfully logged-in');
      // console.log(response);
      // const { data } = response; 
      setUser(data); 
    },
    onError: (err) => {
            const { message } = err.response.data;
      toast.error(message);
      console.log(err);
    },
  });

  return { isPending, mutate };
}
export default useLogin;


Frontend Auth Provider (AuthProvider.jsx): wraps the entire app-tree.
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useControl } from './ControlProvider';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';

const AuthContext = createContext();

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const { setIsLogged } = useControl();
  const [cookies] = useCookies(['jwt']);

  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
    const jwtToken = cookies.jwt;
    if (jwtToken) {
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(jwtToken);
      return decodedToken.userId;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      setIsLogged(true);
    } else {
      setIsLogged(false);
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
  }, [user, setIsLogged]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context)
    throw new Error('Auth context was called outside of its provider');
  return context;
}

export { useAuth };
export default AuthProvider;

Despite successful login requests in Postman, the JWT token is not accessible or manipulable on the frontend, causing users not to remain logged in.
How can I troubleshoot this issue and ensure seamless authentication between the frontend and backend?
